# How to construct a topology from a given basis using subspaces

Tags: general-topology

Please I urgently need a proof of this question using the condition of the basis of subspaces of the topology. I run a math blog and I did half of the proof.  I am left only with the subspace conditions.  You may view my proof at https://mymathware.blogspot.com.ng/2017/08/solutions-to-problems-on-general.html

Consider $S = \{\{a,b\},\{a,c\}\}$, where $X = \{a,b,c\}$. Obtain the topology generated by $S$ $(i.e \mathcal{T}(S))$. Is $S$ a basis?

Comment: S is clearly a subbasis but not a basis. S can't be a basis to any proper subspace of X either since it has all the elements of X.

Comment: Your set of sets is not a basis.  For instance, how is $\{a\}$ ever going to be achievable as an open set by unions?  

You can ask what basis $S$ **generates**, but that's a different question.  Which one do you want answered?

Comment: Clearly not. $\{a, b\}\cap \{a, c\} = \{a\}$, but $\{a\}$ cannot be written as the union of elements in $S$, so $S$ is not the base of any topology.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, $S$ is not a basis, because

$$ \{a,b\} \cap \{a, c\} = \{a\} $$

but $\{a\} \notin S$.

But $S$ still generates a topology, because any collection of sets generates a topology. Remember, a topology $\mathcal{T}$ has the properties that

1. $\mathcal{T}$ contains the empty set and the whole space
2. $\mathcal{T}$ is closed under finite intersections
3. $\mathcal{T}$ is closed under all unions

So here's what we know about our mysterious $\mathcal{T}$ so far. Because it's generated by $S$ it has to contain everything that's in $S$. It has to contain $\varnothing$ and $X$. And it has to be closed under unions and intersections. (The distinction between *finite* intersections and *all* unions is very important in general, but it doesn't matter here because $X$ is finite.)

Our first guess for $\mathcal{T}$ might be to take the sets in $S$, and also add in the empty set and the whole set.

$$ \mathcal{T} \quad ?= \quad \big\{ \varnothing, \{a,b\}, \{a,c\}, \{a,b,c\} \big\} $$

But we haven't included closure under intersections and unions! Remember from above that $\{a,b\} \cap \{a,c\} = \{a\}$. So let's add that in. Our next guess is

$$ \mathcal{T} \quad ?= \quad \big\{ \varnothing, \{a\}, \{a,b\}, \{a,c\}, \{a,b,c\} \big\} $$

Is this the answer, or do we need to add more sets? Walk through the three conditions of a topology above and see for yourself!

Comment: Thank You all, I think i get it now

Answer (score 1):

It's a two-stage process:

If $S$ is a subbase, i.e. a generating set for a topology $\mathcal{T}(S)$, then the set of *all* intersections of finite subfamilies from $\mathcal{S}$ is the base $\mathcal{B}(S)$ generated by $S$. By the axioms for a topology: $$S \subseteq \mathcal{T}(S) \implies \mathcal{B}(S) \subseteq \mathcal{T}(S)$$

The topology generated by $\mathcal{B}(S)$ is the family of *all* unions of subfamilies of $\mathcal{B}(S)$ (in this case everything is finite so we only have finitely many unions to consider). Then we have $\mathcal{T}(S)$.

For your set $S = \{\{a,b\}, \{a,c\}\}$ on $X = \{a,b,c\}$ we then get:

1. The intersection of the *empty* subfamily of $S$, and $\bigcap \emptyset = X$. So $X \in \mathcal{B}(S)$.
2. The intersection of the subfamily $\{\{a,b\}\} \subseteq S$ (a singleton subfamily) which just gives us $\{a,b\}$ again, so $\{a,b\} \in \mathcal{B}(S)$.
3. In the same way: $\{a,c\} \in \mathcal{B}(S)$. (so the empty intersection gives us $X$ (there are many threads on this issue in this forum) and the intersections of singletons gives us that $S \subseteq \mathcal{B}(S))$.
4. There is only other finite subfamily of $S$, namely $S$ itself and $\bigcap S = \{a,b\} \cap \{a,c\} = \{a\}$. This is a new set (unequal to $X$), so $S$ is not a base, but $\{a\} \in \mathcal{B}(S)$.
5. in summary: $\mathcal{B}(S) = \{X, \{a\}, \{a,b\}, \{a,c\}\}$.
6. Now we have to consider all unions of finite subfamilies (a priori, there are 4 members of the base so $2^4  =16$ subfamilies to condider, but we can be a bit lazy):
7. A special case is the empty subfamily again $\bigcup \emptyset = \emptyset \in \mathcal{T}(S)$.
8. A subfamily that has $X$ as one of its members will always have union $X$, which we already have. All members of $\mathcal{B}(S)$ contain $a$, so adding $\{a\}$ to a subfamily never adds anything new. So we only have to consider the union of $\{a.b\}$ and $\{a,c\}$ which is $X$ again (it could have been strictly smaller, e.g. do this whole procedure for $X = \{a,b,c,d\}$ instead..) So nothing new and we have the full topology:
9. $$\mathcal{T}(S) =  \{\emptyset, X, \{a\}, \{a,b\}, \{a,c\}\}$$

This could even be programmed, for finite sets of course. For infinite sets you'll have to reason a bit more, and the process is less algorithmic. But the idea is the same: first all finite intersections (including $X$ and all of $S$), then all unions. This gives the generated topology.